# Good approaches to implement more than one time-critical function using a microcontroller?

Tags: microcontroller

What is the philosophy or approach taken to implementing highly time critical functions in microcontrollers, if there are any?

I am working on a project involving outputting a precise square-wave waveform of varying frequency. I have done this using a timer and an interrupt function. However, even to implement this correctly, I had to calibrate the offset for the number of clock cycles taken during the interrupt service routine. I'd imagine this precision would be disturbed by having another such waveform running alongside (say the frequency needed to be changed at the exact same time). Having a microcontroller each, for every such time critical function seems wasteful.

Take another example, of implementing a clock (as in hh:mm:ss) function. I can't imagine that every high level microncontroller/computer has a dedicated real time clock chip solely to keep track of the time. However, I find it hard to imagine it being accurately measured using the core processor, which is busy servicing a plethora of functions that come at asynchronous intervals in the meantime. I'd imagine the time counting would have offset errors, that change depending on the functions that are running.

Is there a design process or approach to containing or giving a tolerance to the precision achievable? Or does anyone have any pointers or suggestions on where I could find more information regarding this?

Comment: Things that require accurate RTC often do have a dedicated chip, or subfunction with its own power and crystal, in order to keep track of time when the device is switched off. Time is a huge hassle.

Comment: Stop using such a horrible architecture (or start using it correctly) - hardware timers should not depend on time spent in servicing the ISR- so long as reloads are done 'in time' it should not matter.

Comment: What microcontroller?  It would allow better quality answers.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany I must say, I am quite inexperienced in this. The trouble I'm having with the square wave is that I would like the frequency to (be able to) change on every output transition (which for 2 different square waves would be at asynchronous intervals, and could potentially even coincide). A square wave was a smaller part of a bigger question I had in mind. Within waveform generation, how would you implement more than 1 arbitrary analogue waveform? Would the sacrifice be in making a common 'sample rate'?

Comment: @StainlessSteelRat I deliberately did not specify a specific microcontroller as I felt the question was quite broad. For me, it seems it could apply to the processor architecture in large computers through to microcontrollers. In part, I want to know if there are any resources available to learn about making good designs / limiting the error when implementing more than one function which is time sensitive.

Comment: The sacrifice in a uC with appropriate hardware would be using a separate hardware timer for each waveform. Once the output transition on a given timer occurs an interrupt is triggered which results in an update of the time of the next output toggle (details vary by micro)- update the comparison register not the free running counter. The only requirement is that worst case you can service all the interrupts before the timer hits the next compare (which sets an upper limit in the frequency as well as a minimum high and low time).

Answer (score 10):

To output precise square waves, use the hardware.  Most microcontrollers have PWM generators built in that can do this.  You set the period and on time in clock cycles, and the hardware does the rest.  To change it to a new frequency, write the new period into the period register and half the period into the duty cycle register.

As for real time clock losing time due to other load of the processor, it doesn't work that way unless it is very poorly written.  Generally the hardware would be used to create a periodic interrupt that is some multiple of seconds, and the firmware divides further from there.  This works regardless of how busy the processor is, since the interrupt runs whenever it needs to.  As long as the interrupt routine takes a small fraction of the overall cycles, most of the processor is still applied to the foreground task.

There are also ways to keep time by polling at somewhat unknown intervals.  You have the hardware keep a count, and whenever you get around to updating the clock, you update it based on the total number of elapsed ticks.  As long as this routine is run often enough so that whatever counter is used doesn't wrap between runs, no time is lost.

Comment: Sorry! I should've been more broad with my question. A square wave was just a particular example of a time critical application I had in mind. With the PWM generator method you mentioned, would it be able to (if need be) update the frequency on every square wave transition? What if you had to do this for two asynchronous square waves? What about ten? I am wondering if there are any general design approaches to such things. The methods you mention of the periodic interrupt & polling to update the clock are certainly shedding some light.

Comment: @mid: Most micros can interrupt at the start of a PWM period.  Some have double buffered registers so that you can update the parameters during one period, then have them take effect at the start of the next period.  Some micros can feed the PWM via DMA.  I used this once to have the hardware automatically to dithering.

Answer (score 3):

The keyword here is "hardware support". For anything serious you'll need supporting hardware in the µC. The most common integrated peripheral is timer circuitry which runs relatively precisely and without interference from other CPU operations.

Building on that, you can have many functions executing with medium-term timing as precise as your controller's clock source.

But: As you may have already experienced, besides medium- or long-term accuracy there's also always timing *jitter* involved in software handling of hardware events (including things like timer overflow). This is caused by different possible states of execution at the time an event occurs that result in varying delays until the actual response to the event can happen.

Hence, the bottomline is: For anything with high-speed or near-zero jitter requirements, hardware support is essential. Many hardware peripherals are included in most µCs, like UARTs &c, and the more powerful and costly the µC is the more supporting hardware is usually built-in. If your µC does not provide the hardware you'd need, you will indeed have to consider external, dedicated hardware for the task.

Comment: Understanding jitter is key - you can have multiple hardware timers, and they'll all keep track independently, but if they all fire off an interrupt at the same time then not all of them can be serviced at once.

Answer (score 2):

Do as much as you can with hardware, especially for highly time critical functions.  All microcontrollers have timers/counters specifically created to count and time events.

Aside from that, this really is a very broad question.  So there is no good answer.

The only true answer is experience.  Try it, profile it, stress it, fix it.  You have to identify areas of code with high usage.  20% of software running 90% of time, means every instruction removed, improves performance.

Good design has always balanced hardware, software and memory.  This applies to all microprocessors, but especially microcontrollers. Max out one or inefficiently use one and you will have a poor product.  As silicon densities have increased, more and more features are included in the hardware of microcontrollers.  But more features means more expectations.  Double onboard memory and you will add some feature which uses it.

All ISRs have overhead, which is dependent on the registers used by the ISR.  If the latency to save the machine state is significant compared to servicing the ISR for highly time critical functions, your design may not be scalable.  Hence, the general consensus of answers to use hardware.

The use of software interrupts can decrease ISR machine state bloat.

```
// Timer0 ISR
Temp = Temp + 1
if (Temp == 150)
    call Inc_Seconds()
```

All registers for Inc_Seconds() must be pushed, when they are only used once every 150 cycles.

```
// Timer0 ISR
Temp = Temp + 1
if (Temp == 150)
    _Software_Interrupt
...
// Software_Interrupt ISR
    call Inc_Seconds()
```

Now the latency hit only occurs once every 150 cycles.

If you implement a real-time clock in hh:mm:ss, does it matter if it is 50ms off.  No person would detect the error.  This certainly is not a real-time operating concern.

As for events which must occur at the same time.  Must they?  If they must then the hardware design must take care of it.  Otherwise, some software compromise must take place.  If you can't set two bits at one time, then set one bit.  Next instruction set the other.  Accuracy one clock cycle on RISC procesors.  I'd argue that was good enough.

Answer (score 0):

For square waveform you should use a PWM peripheral that is PLLed with your XTAL using some kind of counter to know when to cycle (for setting the fewquency). Every datasheet will tell you how to do this :)

For keeping *time*, yes, you will need a RTC to do it close to accurately unless you go assembler and author opcodes so you know by hand the exact exec timing of each instruction in any exec path. 
It will probably also shed new light on the tried and true 'goto is considered harmful' statement.

Comment: Your comments about the software RTC would only applicable to the most carelessly implemented solutions. A sane and reliable way to do this is to use a hardware timer to generate an interrupt once each 1msec (or 10 msec). In the service routine have a static counter variable that counts then number of interrupts up to 1000 (or 100). When the full count is attained reset the counter and then increment your seconds counter. Every 60 seconds you will reset the seconds counter variable back to zero and increment your minutes counter variable. Extend this all the way to months and years if needed.